# Save infos from "SELECT name AS example" in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, model

I was trying to save information from a column using a different name, but the rails model just cut it out. Is there any way to do this?

In the user model, the "devise" method seems to let me do this

```
>> User.select("name AS test") ## with devise
>> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User test: "admin@test.com", id: nil>, #<User test: "dev@test.com", id: nil>]>



>> User.select("name AS test") ## without devise
>> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil>, #<User id: nil>]>
```

Class code:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise
end
```

I removed everything except devise

Comment: Can you share some code?  What did you try?

Comment: I added to the post

Comment: Your second select should work, can you add your user model and user schema?

Comment: I cleaned the whole class and left only devise to do this

Comment: `User.select("name AS test")` should give you `User`s with `test` attributes even if the `#inspect` output doesn't show the `test`s. What happens if you say `User.select('name as test').map(&:test)`?